# Categorize data preserving all values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, categorical-data

I've got a big set of data, usually a shape `> (700000, 5)`, on which I want to perform multi-parameter regression. All of the variables are dependent on each other. So to start with the multi-parameter regression, I need to split the data into sub-groups of discrete intervals on which I can perform single-parameter regression to get a first "feeling" of the dependencies.

Currently I use `pd.cut` and `df.groupby` methods of `pandas`, which works quite good so far if I want to calculate the mean, sum or whatever of the categorized data. My current code is shown here:

```
# create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'temp_a': np.random.rand(50) * 50 + 20,
                   'temp_b': np.random.rand(50) * 30 + 40,
                   'power_deg': np.random.rand(50),
                   'eta': 1 - np.random.rand(50) / 5},
                  index=pd.date_range(start='20181201', freq='T', periods=50))
# groupby by categorical data:
df_grpd = df.groupby(
    [pd.cut(df.temp_a, np.arange(0, 100, 5)),  # categorical for temp_a
     pd.cut(df.temp_b, np.arange(0, 100, 5)),   # categorical for temp_b
     pd.cut(df.power_deg, np.arange(0, 1, 1 / 20))  # categorical for power_deg
    ]).mean()  # groupby method. THIS is what I do NOT want!
# drop nan
df_grpd = df_grpd[~df_grpd.isna().any(axis=1)]
```

This results in data with a `MultiIndex` like:

```
                                  temp_a    ...          eta
temp_a   temp_b   power_deg                 ...             
...
(35, 40] (40, 45] (0.0, 0.05]  35.086985    ...     0.956543
         (45, 50] (0.5, 0.55]  35.204899    ...     0.866111
                  (0.85, 0.9]  37.018165    ...     0.841505
         (50, 55] (0.9, 0.95]  36.087333    ...     0.978163
(40, 45] (45, 50] (0.15, 0.2]  44.235000    ...     0.906970
...
```

Now I've got the **means of the values of each group**, but I want to **preserve the data of each group**. So instead of using `.mean()` for groupby, I want all values of the groups returned.
Since this requires (at least I guess so) a new level in the MultiIndex for the data, I tried to add another level to `by=[...]` in groupby, but I was not able to make it work in any useful (and presentable) way.
What I want the data to look like:

```
                                            temp_a       ...          eta
temp_a   temp_b   power_deg    some_int_idx              ...             
...
(35, 40] (40, 45] (0.0, 0.05]  1            37.122355    ...     0.851477
                               2            33.455505    ...     0.980045
         (45, 50] (0.5, 0.55]  1            35.204899    ...     0.866111
                  (0.85, 0.9]  1            37.018165    ...     0.841505
                               2            39.998021    ...     0.800158
         (50, 55] (0.9, 0.95]  1            36.087333    ...     0.978163
(40, 45] (45, 50] (0.15, 0.2]  1            44.235000    ...     0.906970
...
```

---

### Summary

I want to have the data of the groups listed by an integer index `some_int_idx`. If there is more than one datapoint per group (since my actual data has alot more datapoints, there will be several thousand datapoints in the "main" groups), `some_int_idx` should number these points. If there is only one (or none) datapoint per group, `some_int_idx` should be `1`. Instead of using an integer index, using the time index would also be ok.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New and much better answer, provided by jorisvandenbossche (thanks!) while filing the bug report:
I can simply set the index with the required intervals. I guess sometimes just thinking the direct and easy way works best...

```
df_grpd = df.set_index([pd.cut(df.temp_a, np.arange(0, 100, 5)),  # categorical for temp_a
     pd.cut(df.temp_b, np.arange(0, 100, 5)),   # categorical for temp_b
     pd.cut(df.power_deg, np.arange(0, 1, 1 / 20))  # categorical for power_deg
    ]).sort_index(axis=0)
```

Old solution:

(Ok, after lots of tests I found an answer. The elements of the groups you get by `groupby` are accessible by the `nth()` method of the `DataFrameGroupBy` object. So you can access all of the group elements and get them as a full dataframe with:

```
# groupby by categorical data, WITHOUT MEAN (or any other grouping method):
df_grpd = df.groupby(
    [pd.cut(df.temp_a, np.arange(0, 100, 5)),  # categorical for temp_a
     pd.cut(df.temp_b, np.arange(0, 100, 5)),   # categorical for temp_b
     pd.cut(df.power_deg, np.arange(0, 1, 1 / 20))  # categorical for power_deg
    ])  # groupby method. Do NOT use this!

df_grpd_full = df_grpd.nth([range(df.shape[0])])
```

The last line may of course also be rewritten with:

```
n_grps = 0
while not df_grpd.nth(n_grps).empty:
    n_grps += 1

df_grpd_full = df_grpd.nth([range(n_grps)])
```

)

### Possible Bug?

But strangely starting with the second group (`df_grpd.nth(1)`), the grouping method seems to be bugged. Only the first groupby parameter, in this case `temp_a` seems to be ok. The other parameters seem to be out of the grouping interval. I'll file a bug report on github and post the link.
[bug report](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24205)